# Receiving Spam from my Form Using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am coming to stackoverflow for this because everything I search pretty much talks about email from a form using PHPMailer going to a users spam box. But, I need info on receiving spam from the form itself. I use it on a small, very light traffic real estate agents website. She gets spam from time to time and I don't know how to resolve it. PHPMailer seems to be the go to tool for sending email with PHP, so I figure spam/security is pretty well covered. I must be doing something wrong.... I am using class.phpmailer.php of course, and here is my code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
  $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
  $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
  $message = trim($_POST["message"]);


if ($name == "" OR $email == "" OR $phone == "" OR $message == "") {
    echo "You must specify a value for name, email address, phone, and message.";
    exit;
}

foreach( $_POST as $value ){
    if( stripos($value,'Content-Type:') !== FALSE ){
        echo "There was a problem with the information you entered.";    
        exit;
    }
}

if ($_POST["address"] != "") {
    echo "Your form submission has an error.";
    exit;
}

require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

if (!$mail->ValidateAddress($email)){
    echo "You must specify a valid email address.";
    exit;
}

$email_body = "";
$email_body = $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
$email_body = $email_body . "Email: " . $email . "<br>";
$email_body = $email_body . "Phone: " . $phone . "<br>";
$email_body = $email_body . "Message: " . $message;

$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
$address = "email@domain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "A Name Here");
$mail->Subject    = "Message from " . $name  . " on website contact form";
$mail->MsgHTML($email_body);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "There was a problem sending the email: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  exit;
}

header("Location: index.php?status=thanks");
exit;
}
```

The HTML is very simple:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="contact-process.php">

    <?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) AND $_GET["status"] == "thanks") { ?>
      <p class="form-thanks">Thank you for contacting us. We'll be in touch with you very soon.</p>
    <?php } ?>

    <label>Name
    <span class="small">First and Last</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

    <label>E-Mail
    <span class="small">name@email.com</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

    <label>Phone Number
    <span class="small">With area code</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />

    <label>Message
    <span class="small">How can we help you?</span>
    </label>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="message"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
```

Comment: You're saying someone sends you Spam from your form, is that the question?

Comment: Then add a CAPTCHA or something. PHPMailer doesn't filter anything by itself.

Comment: @mario Gotta be something better than CAPTCHA. Have a look at http://venturebeat.com/2014/12/03/google-boils-down-the-captcha-to-a-simple-checkbox-to-prove-youre-not-a-bot/

Comment: @Phil Sometimes, it's the simplest of things that we all thought we so complicated.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes, that's my question

Comment: @mario, I would rather not use a big CAPTCHA that sticks out like a sore thumb if possible.

Comment: @ansarob Everyone will receive Spam from time to time and it's rather a broad subject when it comes to *trying* to fight it. As Phil stated in a comment, try a checkbox.

Comment: "**PHPMailer seems to be the go to tool for sending email with PHP, so I figure spam/security is pretty well covered**" well no, it does NOTHING to stop people using your form to send spam, that would be your job

Comment: @phil, thanks for the link. I haven't seen that yet. Cool!

Comment: There's also a piece of code I once saw on the Web a few years ago and I *might* have a copy of it, which would only send mail to the recipient if the person at the other end would click a link in order to verify its email address. The whole thing is kept in `.txt` files and deleted once verified. Quite a nice idea and doesn't require a DB to run it.

Comment: Here, that's what I was talking about ^ http://www.phpkode.com/scripts/item/antispam-feedback/ - but you may have to work it a bit.

Comment: @Dagon is quite right. You're using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an old example. [Update it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: @Synchro I'm using the latest version from Github, so I don't know how it could be old.

Comment: That may be, but your code looks like examples from over a year ago.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple technique to avoid spam is to use something called a honey-pot, which is a text field which is not visible to normal users but a dumb spam-robot will probably enter something into that field.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  // robot detection
  $honeypot = trim($_POST["email"]);     

  if(!empty($honeypot)) {
    echo "BAD ROBOT!"; 
    exit;
  }

  $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
  $email = trim($_POST["real_email"]);
  $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
  $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

  // rest stays as is
```

In your HTML file you need to insert another "hidden" text field which is the honeypot:

```
<label>E-Mail
<span class="small">name@email.com</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="email" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="email_real" id="email" />
```

Note how I changed the name of the actual, visible email text field to "email_real". It would be even better to avoid the word "email" completely in the real email field, since many robots are dumb.

The invisible honeypot input field should be called "email" though. Why? Because most robots are scanning for some standard input fields like "email", "address" etc. - so it's important to give the honeypot a common form field name.

Another neat trick is to swap some common field names, i.e swap the name for email and zip fields, so robots will fill in a numeric value for the email address and an email address for the zip code which will fail the validation.

It's not a 100% guarantee to kill all spam but it worked quite well for me without forcing the user to solve an annoying captcha...

Comment: An old favourite! I wouldn't alert to the fact that the email wasn't sent though, just fail silently

Comment: Great advice! I've implemented that and we'll see how it does. And @Phil, good point.

Comment: Just an update @sled, it seems to have done the trick :) Thank you!

Comment: Very useful even though I'm kinda late to the party here I would also like to say I have used this in the past and for the small amount of spam we would receive this would take care of  business. Thanks @sled