# Adding to mail script using PHPmailer: missing fields validation, redirects

Tags: php, email, redirect, phpmailer

Once upon a time, I had a nicely-functioning version of a mail script that used an old version of PHPmailer. Without really knowing PHP, I managed to push it reasonably far (in part by using Forms to Go and doing some mods), and got it to redirect to both custom "incomplete" and "thank you" pages, and getting it to refuse to send if the required fields weren't filled out.

I've had to go back to the drawing board a bit as now routing domain-based email through Gmail has become a quite dominant practice. In order to get there, I updated to the latest PHPmailer and finally got it functioning for Gmail setup after a lot of trial and error and research. But in the midst of that, I've lost some of that functionality. The script below works to send mail—but it sends even if the required fields (indeed, everything!) are all empty. So it needs to:

1. stop sending when the fields aren't filled in properly, and
2. hopefully redirect to my custom page rather than just display a generic message.

```html
<?php

// CUSTOM: collect data from our web form
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$address = $_REQUEST['address'];
$tel = $_REQUEST['tel'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

//set required fields + redirect if incomplete


//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
//date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;


//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
// Gmail pulls from custom domain due to alteration of MX records
$mail->Host = 'server.mydomain.com';

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 465;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "me@myemailaddress.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "mypassword";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('me@myemailaddress.com', 'web form');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('me@myemailaddress.com', 'My Name');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->clearReplyTos();
$mail->addReplyTo($address);

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $subject;

 $mail->Body = "Name : $name\n\n"
  . "Email : $address\n"
  . "Telephone : $tel\n"
  . "Message :\n\n $message\n"
  . "";


//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
      $output .= "Mailer Error: ". $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    else
    {
       ob_clean();
       header('Location: thankyou.php');
       exit();
    }
    echo $output;
```

Can anyone help me understand how to edit this in order to get that functionality?

A honey pot would be a bonus too, but perhaps that's asking too much. [Edit: Looks like a honey pot solution in this thread will work: [Receiving Spam from my Form Using PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101429/receiving-spam-from-my-form-using-phpmailer) ... will test tomorrow.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <?php
            /**

             */
             if( !isset($_REQUEST['name'],$_REQUEST['address'],$_REQUEST['subject'],$_REQUEST['message']) 
||

( !$_REQUEST['name'] || !$_REQUEST['address'] || !$_REQUEST['subject'] || !$_REQUEST['message'])

){
                    /** 
                     * It means that the required field 
                     * is not filled up all
                     * if any one filed is not required, then remove that from the above condition the whole $_REQUEST['var_not_required']
                     */

                     /**
                      * you can display a error message or redirect       
                      * 1. Error message
                      * 2. Redirect
                      */

                      #1
                      die("Some of the fields are not filled up properly");

                      #2
                      header('location: http://yoururl');
                      /**
                       * Use exit to stop execution of the rest, to prevent sending or attempt to send
                       * with exit
                       */
                       exit();


             }
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
            $address = $_REQUEST['address'];
            $tel = $_REQUEST['address'];
            $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
            $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
```

Comment: Thanks, Abhisek. The empty form still sends successfully when I try your code (edited out #1 and put in the proper URL, of course). :/

Comment: Deleted my last comment. Sorry, yes, Abhisek, that did work. Forgot what I had put on my redirect test page!

Comment: @Abhisek Malakar I have the same question actually PHPMailer is working fine I'm getting emails. but my question is here without validating js mail is sending. I want to validate my js first and then I want to send mail using php mailer.